# Which branch of mathematics is the fuzzy logic?

Tags: linear-algebra, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

Fuzzy logic comes close to boolean algebra but is the upper branch of fuzzy logic (or fuzzy mathematics) still algebra?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: By definition it's not boolean, but it is part of many-valued logic.

Comment: @J.G. okay but still algebra?

Comment: Boolean algebra is definitely not thought of as part of algebra, mostly. It is “an algebra,” but people who study and use them and related ideas are usually not doing “algebra.”

Comment: I think the question is really clear "Which branch of Mathematics is the fuzzy logic?". @Community